# using docker how to copy files from docker to host using docker run

Tags: docker

I have a docker image which has all the required files when I say docker run I would like for it to copy the contents of a folder in docker image to a host directory. After which the docker is not needed and stops

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume/

Answer (score 1):

Mount the host directory to a volume with the run command (`-v` option). In the image copy the files to this volume.